# Handle Dates Over Years

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

I am wanting to display the date column in descending order.  So for example, the way I want it displayed is

> 04/15/2015
>   03/15/2015
>   04/15/2014
>   03/15/2014
>   04/15/2013
>   03/15/2013

However, my query results are displaying in descending order by month.  What should I alter to get the results in my desired formatting?

```
Create Table DateTest
(
  ID int
  ,testdate datetime
)

Insert Into DateTest Values
(1, '2013-03-15 00:00:00.000')
,(2,'2014-03-15 00:00:00.000')
,(3,'2015-03-15 00:00:00.000')
,(4,'2013-04-15 00:00:00.000')
,(5,'2014-04-15 00:00:00.000')
,(6,'2015-04-15 00:00:00.000')

Select ID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TestDate, 101) As [Date] FROM DateTest
ORDER BY [Date] DESC
```

Comment: Because you are sorting it formatted as a `VARCHAR(10)`. That will treat the dates as plain text, and sort accordingly. If you want to sort by actual date, then either don't `CONVERT()`, or make sure to convert it back to a `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `ORDER BY` the original date value, but still `SELECT` the value as a `VARCHAR(10)` like so:

```
Select ID, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), TestDate, 101) As [Date] FROM DateTest
ORDER BY TestDate DESC
```

That will sort them as you desire, and still display them in the `VARCHAR(10)` format.